# Flask-login cannot authenticate

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm sure I'm writing creditinals true and at the console it will redirect me to the dashboard but after it redirect me again into the login page. To fix I've tried to clear cookies but it isn't fixed. After all I tried to print the user after login and it returns AnonymousUserMixin, so I think the problem is about flask-login or sqlalchemy

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password, tFAt):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()


@login_manager.unauthorized_handler
def unauthorized():
    return redirect(url_for("login"))


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        c_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).first()
        if c_user is None:
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        login_user(c_user)
        return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/dashboard")
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = "ABCD"
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 5555, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've Just fixed it with changing this

```
def load_user(username):
    return User.query.filter_by(username = username).first()
```

to

```
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.filter_by(id = id).first()
```

because in the original code returns

```
def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

It must be same with what you are returning, [For more information](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for sharing your solution to this. I have been staring at what ended up being the exact same problem for 4 hours. Good find!